# How to fit a math equation to the line width

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, width

I used the following two equations to implement a branch function:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\NC}{\mathrm{NC}}

\begin{document}

        In Case A, \\


    \begin{equation}
    \Pr\{\mathrm{NC}|\alpha\}= \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
          (1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+p(\alpha + \beta)^{2})^{n-1} & 0\leq \alpha \leq \beta \\
          (1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+4p\alpha\beta)^{n-1} & \beta\leq \alpha \leq \beta-1\\
          (1-p)^{n-1} (1-p(\alpha - \beta)^{2})^{n-1} & 1-\beta\leq \alpha \leq 1 \\

    \end{array} 
    \right.
    \end{equation} \\ 

    In Case B, \\

    \begin{equation} 
    \Pr\{\mathrm{NC}|\alpha\}= \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
          (1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+p(\alpha + \beta)^{2})^{n-1} & 0\leq \alpha \leq \beta \\
          (1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+4p\alpha\beta)^{n-1} & \beta\leq \alpha \leq \beta-1\\
          (1-p)^{n-1} (1-p(\alpha - \beta)^{2})^{n-1} & 1-\beta\leq \alpha \leq 1 \\
    \end{array} 
    \right.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

But the equations exceeded the line width (9&10) or in other words the column words as seen here:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please, also consider that your example doesn't produces shown results.

Comment: Partially done. The code corresponds to image, but I don't see any `\documentclass`, `\usepackage` or `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you want to scale the font such that it fits, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106587/scale-an-equation-to-fit-exact-page-width).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `\\` for ending lines, except where specifically needed (`tabular`, `array` or similar environments) and never leave a blank line before an `equation`.

Narrow columns and `cases` don't go along well, so you have only one possibility: splitting the lines, one part with the value, one with the condition. More generous vertical space will help the reader in understanding what refers to what.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\NC}{\mathrm{NC}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Pr\{\NC|\alpha\}=
\begin{cases}
e^{-2\lambda+\lambda(\alpha+\beta)^{2}} \\
  \qquad \text{for } 0\leq \alpha \leq 1-\beta \\[2ex]
e^{-2\lambda+4\lambda\alpha\beta} \\
  \qquad \text{for } 1-\beta\leq \alpha\leq \beta \\[2ex]
e^{-\lambda-\lambda(\alpha-\beta)^{2}} \\
  \qquad \text{for }\beta\leq \alpha\leq 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
If $0.5 \leq \beta \leq 1$:
\begin{equation}
\Pr\{\NC|\alpha\}=
\begin{cases}
e^{-2\lambda+\lambda(\alpha+\beta)^{2}} \\
  \qquad \text{for } 0\leq \alpha \leq \beta \\[2ex]
e^{-2\lambda+4\lambda\alpha\beta} \\
  \qquad \text{for } \beta\leq \alpha\leq 1-\beta \\[2ex]
e^{-\lambda-\lambda(\alpha-\beta)^{2}} \\
  \qquad \text{for } \beta-1\leq \alpha\leq 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The other set of equations poses more problems, because of the width, so with the standard page parameters the equation number will be shifted: don't worry about it.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\NC}{\mathrm{NC}}

\begin{document}

In Case A,
\begin{equation}
\Pr\{\NC|\alpha\}=
\begin{cases}
(1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+p(\alpha + \beta)^{2})^{n-1}\\
  \qquad \text{for } 0\leq \alpha \leq \beta \\[2ex]
(1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+4p\alpha\beta)^{n-1} \\
  \qquad \text{for } \beta\leq \alpha \leq \beta-1 \\[2ex]
(1-p)^{n-1} (1-p(\alpha - \beta)^{2})^{n-1} \\
  \qquad \text{for } 1-\beta\leq \alpha \leq 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
In Case B,
\begin{equation}
\Pr\{\mathrm{NC}|\alpha\}=
\begin{cases}
(1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+p(\alpha + \beta)^{2})^{n-1} \\
   \qquad \text{for } 0\leq \alpha \leq \beta \\[2ex]
(1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+4p\alpha\beta)^{n-1} \\
  \qquad \text{for } \beta\leq \alpha \leq \beta-1 \\[2ex]
(1-p)^{n-1} (1-p(\alpha - \beta)^{2})^{n-1} \\
  \qquad \text{for } 1-\beta\leq \alpha \leq 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: could you please update your answer as the question has been updated

Comment: there's actually room in the area where the equation number would normally go, so you could fake this out by applying `\mathrlap` to the first line of each group.