# How to fit a multiple lined equation to column width

Tags: column-width

I have an equation with multiple lines that exceeds the column width. I want to modify the equation to fit column width without splitting lines. I've looked at the question [How to fit a math equation to the line width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311219/how-to-fit-a-math-equation-to-the-line-width), but I don't believe it solves my case. I've also tried resizebox without success. Here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%================%
%  New Commands  %
%================%
% Bold math variables
\newcommand{\fb}{\mathbf{f}}
\newcommand{\xb}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\hb}{\mathbf{h}}
\newcommand{\ub}{\mathbf{u}}
\newcommand{\eb}{\mathbf{e}}
\newcommand{\pb}{\mathbf{p}}
\newcommand{\qb}{\mathbf{q}}
\newcommand{\gb}{\mathbf{g}}
\newcommand{\Xb}{\mathbf{X}}
\newcommand{\Zb}{\mathbf{Z}}
\newcommand{\lambdab}{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}
\newcommand{\nub}{\boldsymbol{\nu}}
\newcommand{\mub}{\boldsymbol{\mu}}
\newcommand{\chib}{\boldsymbol{\chi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}\label{eq:unscented_problem_formulation}
    \xb_i := (x_i,y_i,h_i,v_i,\gamma_i,\sigma_i,\phi_i) \in \mathbb{R}^7 \qquad 
    \ub := (u_\phi,u_L) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \qquad \\
    \chib_i \in supp(\varepsilon_T,\phi_T) \qquad
    \forall\,i=1,\dots,N_\chi \\
    \begin{array}{l l}
    \textsf{Min}   
        & J[\xb(\cdot),t_f] := \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\left[(\gamma_i(t_f) - \overline{\gamma}_f)^2 + (\sigma_i(t_f) - \overline{\sigma}_f)^2\right] \\
    \textsf{s.t.} 
        & \dot{\xb}_1 = \fb(\xb_1,\ub,t) \\
        & \vdots \\
        & \dot{\xb}_{N_\chi} = \fb(\xb_{N_\chi},\ub,t) \\
        &\xb_i(t_0) = (0\text{ m},0\text{ m},2000\text{ m},40\text{ m/s},0\text{ rad},0\text{ rad},0\text{ rad}) \\
            &\qquad \forall\,i=1,\dots,N_\chi. \\
        & (t_0,t_f) = (0,1.2) \text{ s} \\
        & \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\gamma_i(t_f) = \overline{\gamma}_f = 0 \\
        & \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\sigma_i(t_f) = \overline{\sigma}_f = 0 \\
        & u_\phi \in [-4\pi,4\pi] \text{ rad} \\
        & u_L    \in [-10000,10000] \text{ N} \\
        & \varepsilon_T\, \sim\, \mathcal{N}(0.003,0.0015^2) \text{ rad} \\
        & \phi_T\, \sim\, \mathcal{U}[0,2\pi] \text{ rad} 
    \end{array}
\end{gather*}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Ideally, I would like to have 'Min' and 's.t.' as far left as possible within the column width. I would also like the expressions after 'Min' and 's.t.' to be aligned. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: isn't this identical to your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692235/how-to-force-a-multilayered-math-environment-to-column-width ?

Comment: There is a subtle difference. The previous question, I learned how to split a single line into two at an obvious breaking point. For this question, I don't want to split the lines, but I want to make sure the current lines fit within column width.

Comment: but that "fitting to column width" was literally the title of your previous question

Comment: Off-topic: It makes no sense to provide a `\label` instruction for an unnumbered group of equations.

Comment: I like to put the label in just in case I want to number the equation later.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions, in no particular order:

- Since the main document font is Times Roman, load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages to have consistency across text and math fonts
- Use an `aligned` environment to typeset everything from the third row onward
- Load the `siunitx` package and learn to use `\unit` and `\qty` to typeset scientific units and their associated quantities.
- Since the `gather*` environment doesn't show, let alone increment, equation numbers, the instruction `\label{eq:unscented_problem_formulation}` will try to associate the label string with whatever counter may have been incremented most recently. Not what you want, is it?

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{%amsfonts, % is loaded by amssymb
            %amsmath,  % is loaded by mathtools  
            mathtools, % for \coloneqq macro
            amsthm, 
            amssymb, 
            array}     % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}
\newcommand\tf{t_{\mkern-2mu f}} % snug up the subscript "f"

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman text and math fonts

\newcommand{\fb}{\mathbf{f}}
\newcommand{\xb}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\hb}{\mathbf{h}}
\newcommand{\ub}{\mathbf{u}}
\newcommand{\eb}{\mathbf{e}}
\newcommand{\pb}{\mathbf{p}}
\newcommand{\qb}{\mathbf{q}}
\newcommand{\gb}{\mathbf{g}}
\newcommand{\Xb}{\mathbf{X}}
\newcommand{\Zb}{\mathbf{Z}}
\newcommand{\lambdab}{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}
\newcommand{\nub}{\boldsymbol{\nu}}
\newcommand{\mub}{\boldsymbol{\mu}}
\newcommand{\chib}{\boldsymbol{\chi}}

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % for \unit and \qty macros

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*} %%%%\label{eq:unscented_problem_formulation}
    \xb_i \coloneqq (x_i,y_i,h_i,v_i,\gamma_i,\sigma_i,\phi_i) \in \mathbb{R}^7 
    \qquad 
    \ub \coloneqq (u_\phi,u_L) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \\
    \chib_i \in\supp(\varepsilon_T,\phi_T) 
    \quad \forall\ i=1,\dots,N_{\chi} \\
\begin{aligned}
\textsf{Min}\     
        & J[\xb(\cdot),\tf] \coloneqq \sum_{i=1}^{N_{\chi}} 
          w_i\bigl[(\gamma_i(\tf) - \bar{\gamma}_f)^2 
                   + (\sigma_i(\tf) - \bar{\sigma}_f)^2\bigr] \\
    \textsf{s.t.}\ \  
        & \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
          \begin{array}[t]{ r C l } % horizontal alignment on "=" symbols
          \dot{\xb}_1 &=& \fb(\xb_1,\ub,t) \\
                      &\vdots& \\
          \dot{\xb}_{N_{\chi}} &=& \fb(\xb_{N_{\chi}},\ub,t) 
          \end{array} \\
        &\xb_i(t_0) = (\qty{0}{\meter}, \qty{0}{\meter}, 
                       \qty{2000}{\meter}, \qty{40}{\meter\per\second}, 
                       \qty{0}{rad}, \qty{0}{rad}, \qty{0}{rad}) \\
        &\qquad\quad \forall\ i=1,\dots,N_{\chi}. \\
        & (t_0,\tf) = (0,1.2)\,\unit{\second} \\
        & {\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{N_{\chi}}}w_i\gamma_i(\tf) = \bar{\gamma}_f = 0 \\
        & {\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{N_{\chi}}}w_i\sigma_i(\tf) = \bar{\sigma}_f = 0 \\
        & u_\phi \in [-4\pi,4\pi]\,\unit{rad} \\
        & u_L    \in [-10000,10000]\,\unit{\newton} \\
        & \varepsilon_T\sim \mathcal{N}(0.003,0.0015^2)\,\unit{rad} \\
        & \phi_T\sim \mathcal{U}[0,2\pi]\,\unit{rad} 
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a particular format in mind. I've edited my question to describe the formatting I'm looking for.

Comment: @Shelley - I think my answer already covers all of your added requirements, except the position of "s.t.". I'll tweak its position now.

Comment: 'x_1' is also not aligned with the rest of the constraints

Comment: @Shelley - Have you actually bothered to look into the code -- including the comment "horizontal alignment on "=" symbols" -- to find out what's going on with the `\dot{\xb}_1` row? The rows from `\dot{\xb}_1` thru `\dot{\xb}_{N_{\chi}}` are placed in an `array` environment, aligned on the `=` symbols. I added this structure as a visual guide to the reader's eye. Evidently, though, this is way too much structure for your taste. Well, just remove the `array`-related overhead code to force left-alignment of the three rows in question and be happy. I'm not going to change my answer any further.